# How can one control variables but ensure that the population is representative?

Tags: experiment-design, research-design, representative

Usually, you want to control variables within a study. However, you also want to obtain a representative population to the population that you're measuring. How can one even strike a balance between the two? Is it by splitting the population into specific groups with the specific RELEVANT control variables, as you specified in this link ([Is controlling variables important in deducing a statistically significant correlation?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/278206/is-controlling-variables-important-in-deducing-a-statistically-significant-corre/278226#278226)), and then observe the relevant outcomes?

I think that representation is also confusing because because I think to myself *just because certain people live within a neighborhood, is there necessarily a link between them?* There are probably certain aspects of representation which we have not been able to study yet.

Comment: This read might address some of your concerns: [Why representativeness should be avoided](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24062287)

Comment: In the related question, you've asked me to look at this one as well (at Mathematician), I have, and the link @ManuelFazio provided provides an excellent and also detailed answer to how representative your study population has to be (or not). A short example I can readily give is the following: the 'god' amongst studies types, *the RCT* almost never has a perfectly representative study population. As in, due to the strict in- and exclusion criteria, specific patients groups (which might be the most important), often get left out (think of children, pregnant women, elderly, etc.).